# Pass jquery variable get from database from ajax to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

while am clicking button,it should display the count value (from database) below the button

```
<button id="update">update</button>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#update').click(function(){
                var complete = 0;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    URL: "functions/doneex.php", 
                    data: {
                        complete: complete 
                    },
                    success: function(res) {
                        //alert(res);

                    }
                });       
            }); 
        })
    </script>

    <?php
        echo $res ;

    ?>
```

(get value from db)it is called by ajax

```
doneex.php 
    $query=$conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(isdone) AS complete FROM $today_workout_tbl WHERE isdone=1");
        $query -> execute();
        $query -> bind_result($complete);
        $query -> fetch();
        $query -> close();
        echo $complete;
```

Comment: Please be more concrete on what you want to do. Though this maybe clear to you, from the position of someone reading it it's very unclear.

Comment: what you are trying to do here can not work at all. please have a think about where which code gets executed, then you'll notice that the javascript variable `res` can never reach your php code.

Comment: that is not possible, once server side code is executed you cannot deal with it on client side..

Comment: while i am clicking the button,it should display the count value from database below the button.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can access the data passed in a post request by using the built-ins gobals arrays: 
    $res = $_REQUEST['res']  
To include them into the ajax request you got to: retrieve the value of the  
form element, e.g.: 
var valueOfResField = $('[name=res]').value
and send it via the ajax request:

```
 $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             URL:"functions/doneex.php", 
             data:{complete :complete, res: valueOfResField},
             success:function(res){
              //alert(res);
             $("#done").html(res);

            }});
```

If you want to process this variable value in PHP and get the modified value back into the form, you would have to store the value on the server and make an ajax call to retrieve the value again and modify the value in the displayed html page.

Answer (score 0):

The question is pretty vague but I think you want to look at setting the data type of your .ajax call to be JSON and then return data from the PHP script using json_encode(...). This is the easy (and readable) way to get at the data you return from the PHP script (doneex.php in your example).

Here is an example:

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/do_php_stuff.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'pid=' + personid ,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: successCallback
});

function successCallback(response, status) {
    if (response.ok) {
       alert(response.data);
    }
}
```

PHP (/ajax/do_php_stuff.php)

```
<?php
   echo json_encode(Array('ok' => true, 'data'='hello');
?>
```

Applying this to your updated question:

```
<button id="update">update</button>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#update').click(function(){
            var complete = 0;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                URL: "functions/doneex.php", 
                data: {
                    complete: complete 
                },
                dataType: 'json'
                success: function(res) {
                    alert(res.complete);

                }
            });       
        }); 
    })
</script>

<?php
    echo $res ;
?>
```

(get value from db)it is called by ajax

doneex.php

```
$query=$conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(isdone) AS complete FROM $today_workout_tbl WHERE isdone=1");
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($complete);
$query->fetch();
$query->close();
echo json_encode(Array('complete' =>$complete));
```

But the "echo $res" in the first script will be rendered when the script is output which is before the ajax runs,... so that part will never work. If you are running PHP at this point you should just wrap the stuff from doneex.php in a function and call it from both scripts! Or, if you want it to update when you click the button then place the value in a  and use jQuery to set the text inside the div with .text()

Comment: one issue is that 'data' in the ajax call is what is passed TO the PHP call not what is returned.

Comment: php code and ajac call in same page and database code in other php